# In App Purchase: Application is Live and still showing [Environment: Sandbox]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

My Application is live on app store and working In App Purchase. In App purchase dialog show environment sandbox. When can i get the environment live for in app purchase? Can anybody having same issue.. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I resolve this issue.

Solution: Remove app from device. Restart Device and Downloaded App From App Store.

Problem occurred, I was using the same device for testing. and before downloading app from app

from i forget to restart device.

well, Its working for me now... :)

Answer (score 4):

Do you see this in the app, that you have downloaded from the App Store or from your Xcode build? In the second case, it is OK, because when building from Xcode,you'll be sandboxed.
If you download it from App Store, it will be in normal mode.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have downloaded app from app store. But still it getting confirmation message with Environment:Sandbox